# Highstock: two panes rendering issue with touch zoom / move

Tags: highcharts

When viewing the [Highstock two pane example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) on a touch device, moving the chart by touchdrag, or performing a pinch zoom causes the chart to render the second pane incorrectly (looks like it ignores the yAxis offset).

Any thoughts for a workaround / config change that might help?

Comment: You can that when you touchtrag i.e to right then offset is bigger? (left gap) ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan - I'm not sure what you mean by that. Sorry for the late reply on this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, so I reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2000